# Creating a set number of instances of an entity from a single form submit

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to insert into a database a set number of instances of an entity from a single form submit.

Lets say for example I have an entity called "Assignement" which assigns an employee to a department.

Supposedly I select 3 different employees to assign at the same time to 3 different departments. I thus want my sql transaction to insert 9 times the said "Assignement" instance in my database with different user and departement values each time.

I am using Symfony 2 as a framework and Doctrine as an ORM.

I've done some research and I tried fiddling with the controller and the doctrine query builder but no results so far.

Does anyone have an idea on how to engage the issue? Any lead I could follow?

Comment: Is `employee` an entity? Is `department` an entity? Do you have a join / relationship table for this setup with Doctrine?

Comment: Yes, both "Employee" and "Department" are entities. I have a ManyToOne relationship between them, as in many Employees can be assigned to one Department.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html